# Creating a new column in DataFrame based on another column and unique identifier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to append a column called `time` to my pre-existing dataFrame `df1`. The values for my new column `time` are derived using the unique identifier column `snapshot` which exists in both `df1` and `df2` to link them.

I've tried to leverage both `apply` and `lambda` to help me create this column but it doesn't work.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'product' : ['PENS', 'PENS', 'PENS', 'PENS', 'PENS','STAPLER','STAPLER'],
                'price' : [20,25,35,40,70,100,140],
                'snapshot' : [1,2,3,4,5,1,2]})

???df1
price  product  snapshot
0     20     PENS         1
1     25     PENS         2
2     35     PENS         3
3     40     PENS         4
4     70     PENS         5
5    100  STAPLER         1
6    140  STAPLER         2

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'snapshot' : [1,2,3,4,5],
               'publish_time' : ['10/10/2005', '2/19/2007', '6/20/2007', '7/10/2010', '7/15/2010']})

>>>df2
publish_time  snapshot
0   10/10/2005         1
1    2/19/2007         2
2    6/20/2007         3
3    7/10/2010         4
4    7/15/2010         5   

df1['time'] = df1['snapshot'].apply(lambda x : df2['publish_time'].loc[df2['snapshot'] == x])

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1
```

Ideally what I want is this something like this:

```
>>>df1
    price  product         time  snapshot
 0     20     PENS   10/10/2005         1
 1     25     PENS    2/19/2007         2
 2     35     PENS    6/20/2007         3
 3     40     PENS    7/10/2010         4
 4     70     PENS    7/15/2010         5
 5    100  STAPLER   10/10/2005         1
 6    140  STAPLER    2/19/2007         2
```

Comment: this is merge problem

Comment: @W-B you're absolutely correct, I was using the wrong function! Thanks.